# How to only return primary contacts like in the Android People app

Tags: android, contacts

I'm trying to pull a list of contacts and attaching all of the contacts associated with a given person.  The problem I am having is that my query is returning back all contacts that have ever been emailed.  I don't want to include every contact I've emailed however, I just want the main contacts (like what is displayed in the built-in People app).

In the code below I was trying to limit the emails by using a ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI query to limit the returned emails, but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private ArrayList<ContactFriend> allContacts;
private Cursor contactsCursor;
private Cursor emailCursor;

void load() {
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(CONTACTS_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(EMAILS_LOADER_ID, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if (id == CONTACTS_LOADER_ID) {
        String[] projection = {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
        };
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " ASC";
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                    sortOrder);
    } else if (id == EMAILS_LOADER_ID) {
        String[] projection = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
        };
        String sortOrder =
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + ", " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " ASC";
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                            projection,
                            null,
                            null,
                            sortOrder);
    } else {
        // should never happen
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    int id = loader.getId();
    if (id == CONTACTS_LOADER_ID) {
        contactsCursor = cursor;
    } else if (id == EMAILS_LOADER_ID) {
        emailCursor = cursor;
    }

    if (contactsCursor != null && emailCursor != null) {
        init();
    }
}

void init() {
    if (allContacts == null) {
        allContacts = getAllContacts();
    }
    // do stuff with allContacts
}

private ArrayList<ContactFriend> getAllContacts() {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> emails = getEmailMap();
    ArrayList<ContactFriend> result = new ArrayList<ContactFriend>();

    contactsCursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String name = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY));
        String photo = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));
        int id = contactsCursor.getInt(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        ArrayList<String> contactEmails = emails.get(id);
        if (!contactEmails.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(new ContactFriend(name, contactEmails, photo, id));
        }
    } while (contactsCursor.moveToNext());
    return result;
}

private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> getEmailMap() {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> result = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

    while (contactsCursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = contactsCursor.getInt(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        result.put(id, new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    Set<Integer> contactIds = result.keySet();
    while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = emailCursor.getInt(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID));
        if (contactIds.contains(id)) {
            String email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
            result.get(id).add(email);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this in case someone else has the same problem.  Adding ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP to the projection and then selecting only those entries where that value is equal to 1 gives me what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi Matt, I am having this same problem, but I only use a String projection, not a selection, so what did you mean by **selecting only entries where value is equal 1**?

Comment: @Noni If you want to limit the returned rows/contacts to only include the visible ones you need to not only include ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP in your projection but you also need a selection for that column like `String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "==1";`  In my code above, that selection variable then becomes the fourth parameter in the CursorLoader.